# How to return random string from a non binary tree in java

Tags: java

I have a method to return a String from a non binary tree but its throwing "IllegalArguementException" What am I doing wrong.

```
 public String getRandomWord(Node node, String word){
      Random randomGenerator = new Random(); 
      randomInt = 0;
      current = node;
      if(node.getChildren() == null){
           //System.out.println(node.getData());
           return word;
      }
      while(node.getChildren() != null){
           randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(node.getChildren().size());
           randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
           current = node.getChildren().get(randomInt);
           word += current.getData(); 
           //System.out.print(current.getData()+"\n");
           getRandomWord(current, word);
      }
      return word;
}
```

---

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
 at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:604)
 at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:382)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:71)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Tree.getRandomWord(Tree.java:74)
 at treeapp.Main.main(Main.java:34)
 Java Result: 1
```

Comment: The stracktrace is always helpful. Include it next time please.

Comment: I suspect `node.getChildren().size()` is returning something non-positive (perhaps 0?).

Comment: Yes but why? What's the way out ?

Comment: When `node.getChildren()` is empty, you receive that exception as a result of trying to access child `0` of the list when no children exist.  Maybe you mean to check `node.getChildren().isEmpty()`, rather than `node.getChildren() != null`?

Comment: I caught the exception and everything seems OK :) Thanks

Comment: In most cases, it's better to modify code to avoid an exception like this rather than to simply catch it.  I recommend you make such modifications, as they seem as if they'll be fairly simple in this case, since the exception is only caused when the children list is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to delete this line, which will overwrite the previous random number and assumes that there are always 2 children.

```
randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
```

Also, I'm not sure exactly what the method is supposed to do, but you may want to change the `while` to an `if` if I understand it correctly.

Finally, change `if(node.getChildren() == null)` to `if(node.getChildren().size()==0)`. When the node has no children, `getChildren()` returns an empty list, not `null`.